# Impact of 'this' keyword in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have noticed that Google Chrome debugger behaves quite differently depending on how a JS object is created;

If I create an js object like this;

```
var SonA = function(thename) {
               this.firstname = thename || "Graham";
               this.age = 31;
}

SonA.prototype = new Father();
```

Then Chrome's debugger doesn't allow me to drill down and view the prototype. It does however give me key value pairs of the instance variables name and age.

However, if I omit the `this` keyword, I am able to drill down to the prototype, but I do not get the instance variables displayed in the debugger.

```
//SonB doesn't use this keyword    
var SonB = function(thename) {
                  firstname = thename || "Graham";
                  age = 31;
           } 

SonB.prototype = new Father();
```

```
console.log(new SonA()); //this logs as: SonA {firstname: "graham", age: 31}
console.log(new SonB()); //this logs as as drill down object that shows the prototype
```

Does anyone know what is going on here, and why the behavior of the debugger is different? The following image and jsfiddle may make the issue clearer to understand;

[image: Screenshot]

http://jsfiddle.net/7z8sp/1/

Comment: Use `console.dir` http://jsfiddle.net/7z8sp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what it is you're trying to achieve. The only reason *why* you can *"drill down"* to the prototype in `sonB`, is because the constructor isn't setting any properties, but it's creating *implied globals*. Just add this line to your fiddle:

```
console.log(age);//<--logs 31
```

It logs the values that are being set by the `sonB` constructor. If you want to get at the prototype-properties, you either: delete the child's property, or you use the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method.

To clarify: this isn't inherent to the debugger, but to the way JS gets the values and properties of an object. consider the following:

```
var emptyObject = {};
console.log(emptyObject.someProperty);//logs undefined
Object.prototype.someProperty = 'YaY';
console.log(emptyObject.someProperty);//logs YaY
emptyObject.someProperty = function()
{
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).someProperty;
};
console.log(typeof emptyObject.someProperty);//function
console.log(emptyObject.someProperty());//YaY again
delete(emptyObject.someProperty);//returns true
console.log(emptyObject.someProperty);//logs YaY.
```

What does this mean: simply put, if you attempt to access a property on *any* object (arrays, objects, functions, the lot) JS will *first* check if that particular instance has that property defined, if it doesn't, then JS steps up a level in the *prototype-chain*. If that prototype doesn't have the requested property, JS skips to the next prototype, and so on. If no property was found, `undefined` will be  returned. 
It therefore stands to reason that, if your constructor sets certain properties, JS won't bother with the prototypes and return the properties ASAP.

The same logic applies to *implied globals*. If variables are missing the `var` keyword, JS scans the *scopes* (current function, "parent" function(s), and eventually the global scope) in search of that variable. If it is found, that variable will be either used or reassigned (depending on what you're doing with it in your code). If no variable was found, then JS will kindly create one for you. Sadly, without bothering to return to the current scope. The result: a global variable is created. 
In your code, the `Father` constructor, creates a new function object for each instance. This unction relies on a closure variable (`sirname`) and a *global* variable (`firstname`). The latter isn't being set by `SonA`, because that constructor assigns a new property. `SonB`, however, does create the global variable that both `SonA` and `SonB` will share.

The only reason why the `getName` member function of `Father` is working on `sonB`, is because that method, too, relies on *scope-scanning* and an implied global:

```
new SonB();//<-- constructor sets age and firstname globals
SonB.getName();//<-- ~= Father.getName.apply(SonB,arguments);
     ||
     ---> gets firstname global that was set in SonB constructor, uses that value
```

That's all there is too it, just redefine Father's getName method to:

```
this.getName = function()
{//use this to point at calling context -> IE the instance on which the member function is being invoked
    return this.firstname + ' ' + surname;
};
```

Comment: *"The only reason why you can "drill down" to the prototype in sonB, is because the constructor isn't setting any properties"* But I think that's the question he's asking. Why does one allow you to expand the object, and the other does not. In other words, he's asking why they use two different displays for objects.

Comment: @user1689607: to which the answer is simple: _because he's using implied globals_, and thus the global object, not the objects themselves. I'm a bit of a mess ATM, but I'll try to clarify

Comment: But why would that make a difference in how they display the object? I can't reproduce it so I can't test, but it would seem odd that the presence of actual properties on the object would make it *not* expandable.

Comment: @user1689607: Most debuggers show a variable, and -if that var is an object- show a couple of the properties that are bound to that particular instance. In the first case `age` and `firstname` are properties (they're being assigned to `this`), in the second case, no properties are being created, so there's nothing to show for that object, except for the prototype

Answer (score 1):

Using `Console.dir()` instead works: http://jsfiddle.net/7z8sp/3/

Answer (score 1):

With 24.0.1312.5 (Official Build 166104) beta, I'm getting this:

```
SonA
    age: 31
    firstname: "Graham"
    __proto__: Father
        getName: function () {
        __proto__: Object

SonB
    __proto__: Father
        getName: function () {
        __proto__: Object
```

Which is correct, since without `this` you are assigning the `age` and `firstname` on the global object (`window` in this case). Run in the context of the `result` iframe:

```
> firstname
"Graham"
> age
31
```